# Keyboard cuts input field on small screen

Tags: android, keyboard, edittextpreference

I use standart EditTextPreference but on different Android versions it looks differently:

API 7
[image]

API 10
[image]

[image]

How can I achieve good view? Maybe resize keyboard or something else?

Comment: Try changing  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helped me solve the problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8481314/1752613

```java
public class MyEditTextPreference extends EditTextPreference
{
    public MyEditTextPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void showDialog(Bundle bundle) {
        super.showDialog(bundle);

        Dialog dialog = getDialog();
        if(dialog != null) {
            Window window = dialog.getWindow();
            window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE |
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
        }
    }
}
```